# Fluent NHibernate insert record to many to many relationship database

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have a database of three tables:

```
FaceT    PhotoT     FacePhotoT
------   ------     ----------
FaceID   PhotoID    FaceID
Name     Name       PhotoID
                    Some additional columns
```

Actually, its two one to many relationships because of additional columns in link table. Anyway, inserting completely new records is working fine, but the question is, how I suppose to do record insert if I just want to insert new face to existing photo record? I get fresh new face name and existing photo name in which that face exists and what to do? I cannot create another photo record, because there are such file with same name uploaded to server (Name column in Photo table is unique), I have to check somehow if photo doesn't exist in the database and if it does, create records only in two other tables (FaceT and FacePhotoT), but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the following entity and mapping for `PhotoT`:

```
public class PhotoT
{
    //your entity's other properties here
    public virtual IList<FaceT> Faces { get; set; }

    public PhotoT()
    {
        Faces = new List<FaceT>();
    }
}

public class PhotoTMap : ClassMap<PhotoT>
{
    public PhotoTMap()
    {
        //mapping for other properties here
        HasManyToMany(x => x.Faces)
            .Cascade.SaveUpdate() //or another Cascade option of your choice
            .Inverse() //or Inverse on FaceT
            .Table("FacePhotoT")
            .ParentKeyColumn("PhotoID")
            .ChildKeyColumn("FaceID");
    }
}
```

You could just add a new `FaceT` to the collection of an existing `PhotoT` record like this:

```
PhotoT photo = session.Get<PhotoT>(1);
FaceT face = new FaceT();
photo.Faces.Add(face);
session.Update(photo);
tx.Commit();
```